# How to add a html element to Value in Array JSON, Typescript, Angular

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I want to add some Dynamic data to my Angular Project, I have a JSON file which has the Data and, I am fetching it from typescript and using it in my html. I want to store a HTML element in a value and then use it in my html so, I did it and it just shows me the HTML element in the result, like:
If i write

```
[
 {
  "element": "<h1>Element<h1>"
 }
]
```

Then the result in browser is:

```
<h1>Element<h1>
```

Instead of showing a `h1` **Element**

Will appreciate a answer!

Comment: For example: <span [innerHtml]=“element”></span> Should do the trick..

Comment: Didn't work gave me an error, I did like this ```<div [innerHtml]="{{ data.content }}"></div>```

Answer (score 0):

Try innerHtml

```
<div *ngFor="let li of list">
  <div [innerHTML]="li.elem"></div>
</div>
```

ts

```
  list = [{
    elem: "<h3>Hello</h3>"
  }, {
    elem: "<h3>World</h3>"
  }];
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qbg51b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: No it's not working, It just shows the text inside tags in Normal text format like when I place a ```<button>``` inside it it shows the Text not as a button but like normal text without any styling

Comment: It also not works in the code you gave:https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNeup5-7EVGzlqym_CAhfp-m0YAXKcbPsjkgFUivx6x0wQjjUl19AzxKYWyRVEwpg/photo/AF1QipM-457-j7Z1IEKRF4DCxqxbVrDq372PBn6PV9Oi?key=aU5xdjBON1pLWUVpV1ZBV19FM2NlNlVZT1JTV0xn Please help... but anyways thanks for taking time to answering my question

Comment: Please tell me some other way